# How to force Grails to use proper column type in MySQL for Map field

Tags: mysql, grails, database, hibernate-mapping, autocreate

I have a problem in Grails 1.1.2 + MySQL.

My domain class Something contains field

```
Map<String, Map<Integer, Integer>> priceMap
```

When I run the app, Grails creates table 'something' and sub-table 'something_price_map'. 'something_price_map' contains

```
BIGINT(20) price_map
VARCHAR(255) price_map_idx
TINYBLOB price_map_elt
```

The problem is that when I fill-in the column priceMap even with small map data like this 'priceMap:[en:[100:4, 500:20, 600:24]]', the size of the data exceeds the limit of 255bytes.

Is there any way of specifying maxSize constraint for the inner map (Map), so that Grails uses MEDIUMBLOB or BLOBK instead of TINYBLOB?

Btw... Using in-mem DB, everything works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you may know, there is a [mapping constraint](http://www.grails.org/GORM+-+Mapping+DSL) for a domain class. However, your issue may be too complex for that functionality.

In such cases, you can specify an [explicit Hibernate mapping](http://www.grails.org/Hibernate+Integration) (via hbm file) for a domain class. This allows the complete flexibility of Hibernate.

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem - the complexity. For simple map I could use maxSize constraint, but I need to specify the maxSize for inner map.

Thanks for recommendation of hbm file. If I don't find better solution, I will try this one.